# How to make DatePickerDialog's setMinDate different from "setCurrentDate"?

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I'm using a DatePickerDialog to select a begin / end Date to search in an article list.

Thing is DatePickerDialog's setMinDate actually set also default position of dialog box when opened and block user from selecting an anterior date:

Here's my date gestion method:

```
 private void createDisplay(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,
            dateSetListener,
            day, month, year);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    dialog.show();
}
```

I mean, it should be today as default position but if I use setMinDate I can't select an anterior position of today's date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this -

Example:

```
// Adding 3 days
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);

// Set the Calendar new date as maximum date of date picker
dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

// Subtract 6 days from Calendar updated date
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -6);

// Subtract 6 months from Calendar updated date
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
```

Or you can use

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
```

**Note** - put any date as you wish and modify it like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
formatter.setLenient(false);

Date curDate = new Date();
long curMillis = curDate.getTime();
String curTime = formatter.format(curDate);

String oldTime = "05.01.2011, 12:45";
Date oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
long oldMillis = oldDate.getTime();
```

And then

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(oldMillis);
```